# What would be the correct word for considering or believing something said by people without knowing the truth behind it?

Tags: synonyms

For example, some people have heard that we should not eat late, and they believe it, without knowing the reason behind it.

Comment: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/credulous    Credulous, gullible, naive, and unquestioning are all words that can describe those who believe what they hear without question or checking the facts. To respond more directly to the question, a term that might describe the behavior they're exhibiting is "blind faith".

Comment: Or for a phrase: "taking on-faith" the truth of something.

Comment: *Unquestioning* (as per @IsabelArcher) + *accepting* suggests *unquestioning acceptance* as an apt description of the behavior in question.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the expression "*to take it on faith that...*". This expression introduces an idea which is accepted without further verification. Merriam-Webster defines it as:
to accept (something) as true without proof or evidence that it is true ~ [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accept%2Ftake%20%28something%29%20on%20faith)

Consider: "He just took it on faith that I was being a responsible and didn't ask any more quesitons."

Answer (score 0):

One term describing an unverified claim in your context may be:

### Old wive's tale

> an often traditional belief that is not based on fact ~ [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old%20wives%27%20tale)
>
> a traditional belief, story, or idea that is often of a superstitious nature. ~ [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/old-wives--tale#)

You may also want to consider **superstition** and **urban legend**, but these terms invoke particular connotations and may be out-of-context in your case. Superstition tends to be associated with ominous or supernatural forces. Urban legend tends to be associated with horror or humor.